# Google Script to get JSON from cURL

Tags: json, google-apps-script, curl, http-headers, urlfetch

I'm trying to get the data from [this site (stats.nba.com)](https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shots-closest-defender/?Season=2021-22&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&CloseDefDistRange=6%2B%20Feet%20-%20Wide%20Open&DateFrom=10%2F01%2F2021&DateTo=11%2F08%2F2021) as a json object using cURL in a Google Script so that I may import it to a Google Sheet.

Here is my function so far:

```
function IMPORTNBA() {
  var url = "https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shots-closest-defender/?Season=2021-22&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&CloseDefDistRange=6%2B%20Feet%20-%20Wide%20Open&DateFrom=10%2F01%2F2021&DateTo=11%2F08%2F2021"
  var headers = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"95\", \"Chromium\";v=\"95\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "x-nba-stats-token": "true",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36",
    "x-nba-stats-origin": "stats",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
    "Origin": "https://www.nba.com",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Referer": "https://www.nba.com/",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 08 Nov 2021 22:57:01 GMT"
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers)
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())

  return data;
}
```

The fetch isn't executing as I hoped because the response output looks  not like json, but like this (truncated):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" lang="en" ng-app="stats" ng-strict-di stats-version="4.46.1" stats-build-date="2021-11-05 08:03 PM">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">

    
      
    

    <title> Teams Opponent Shooting Dashboard Closest Defender | Stats | NBA.com</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description"  content="A table featuring opponent shooting dashboard information for each team in the league based on selected filters."  />

        <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shots-closest-defender/?CloseDefDistRange=6%2B%20Feet%20-%20Wide%20Open&amp;DateFrom=10%2F01%2F2021&amp;DateTo=11%2F08%2F2021&amp;Season=2021-22&amp;SeasonType=Regular%20Season">
    
        <base href="/stats/teams/opponent-shots-closest-defender/">
    
    
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shots-closest-defender/?CloseDefDistRange=6%2B%20Feet%20-%20Wide%20Open&amp;DateFrom=10%2F01%2F2021&amp;DateTo=11%2F08%2F2021&amp;Season=2021-22&amp;SeasonType=Regular%20Season" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="NBA Stats" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Teams Opponent Shooting Dashboard Closest Defender" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="A table featuring opponent shooting dashboard information for each team in the league based on selected filters." />
  <meta property="og:image" content="/stats/media/img/touch/stats-icon-152x152.png" />
  <meta property="og:sport" content="Basketball" />
  <meta property="og:sports_league" content="NBA" />

  
  
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/stats/manifest.json">

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#051c2e">

    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="application-name" content="NBA Stats">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="NBA Sta
```

Am I not entering accurate headers?

Edit: cURL command:

```
curl 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashoppptshot?CloseDefDistRange=6%2B+Feet+-+Wide+Open&College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=10%2F01%2F2021&DateTo=11%2F08%2F2021&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&DribbleRange=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&GeneralRange=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2021-22&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&ShotDistRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TouchTimeRange=&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'x-nba-stats-token: true' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-nba-stats-origin: stats' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'Origin: https://www.nba.com' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: https://www.nba.com/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon, 08 Nov 2021 22:57:01 GMT' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: I think that your HTML is not JSON. So I cannot understand your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of `truncated` of `The fetch isn't executing as I hoped because the response output looks not like json, but like this (truncated):` and your expected value?

Comment: Truncated meant I didn't paste the whole HTML because it was just to show that the response was HTML and not json. When I execute a cURL, I get a json response.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide your curl command of `When I execute a cURL, I get a json response.`?

Comment: It wouldn't fit in this reply with the limited character count, but I updated the original post to show the cURL at the botttom.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. When I saw your curl command, I think that your script is required to be modified from `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers)` to `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers})`. By this, the same request with the curl command is achieved. But, when I tested it, I confirmed the long process time. In your URL, how much size is the data from the URL?

Comment: It's only a 30 by 16 table. 18KB in Notepad. Not loading that small amount of data is what made me confused. Because it takes mere milliseconds with cURL.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I tested the modified script, the script occurs a timeout error. So I'm worried that this URL cannot be accessed from the Google domain. By the way, in the current stage, `User-Agent` cannot be changed with UrlFetchApp. So, also I'm worried about this. I apologize that I cannot clearly answer your issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I recently used it for a GAS project of my own:
https://gist.github.com/cms-jakes/751cf7cacfc59e63491338cba6359e9e

The approach they took was to first get all the script properties, modify them appropriately, and then save them as the new header. This might be a more effective approach rather than writing the header from scratch as there may be some property you're missing.